# Existe algum histórico da pergunta além do histórico de edição?

Tags: suporte, edição, votação

Sei que é possível ver o histórico de edição de uma pergunta ou resposta se clicarmos ali em `editada DATA/HORA DA EDIÇÃO`:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Mas, será que o site fornece mais informações sobre o histórico de uma pergunta/resposta?

Answer (score 10):

Sim, cada post tem uma [Linha do Tempo (timeline)](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/4743/timeline) que pode ser acessada através da URL:

```
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/POST_ID/timeline
```

Sendo `POST_ID` o ID da pergunta ou resposta. A Linha do Tempo da **Pergunta** mostra todas as atividades, respostas incluidas. As atividades incluem votos, comentários, aceitação de resposta, fechamento e reabertura da pergunta, e outras. A Linha do Tempo da **Resposta** mostra essas atividades porém restritas somente àquela resposta.

Para facilitar o acesso, pode-se usar um [Userscript](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/userscripts/info) como [*View Post Timeline*](https://stackapps.com/q/4148/10590) do Stack Apps.

O script na pergunta do usuário *pascalhein* produz este link abaixo da estrela de Favoritos:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

E o script na resposta do usuário *Brock Adams* adiciona os links *revisions* e *timeline* abaixo da pergunta, junto com os links padrão (*revisions* leva para o histórico de edição do post):

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Antigamente, só a pergunta tinha timeline, mas recentemente uma [nova timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165628/timeline-should-show-user-names-associated-with-opening-and-closing/165635#165635) foi estreada e que inclui a visualização separada das atividades de uma resposta. Prefiro o script do Brock, e fiz a seguinte alterção para remover o link `revisions` (acho redundante) e mostrar o link `timeline` também nas respostas:

```js
// SUBSTITUIR O BLOCO INTEIRO: if(idMtch...){...}
if (idMtch.length > 2) {
    var id  = idMtch[1];
    jThis.append (
        '<span class="lsep">|</span><a href="/posts/' + id + '/timeline">timeline</a>'
    );
}
```